# Moshi JsonAdapter.Factory: Same type of fields, but different String format in Json

Tags: java, json, moshi

I've exposed my problem [on Moshi GitHub](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/597).

Resume: how to deserialize a json into a class which have 2 fields of same type, but different JSon formats, using custom annotation for these formats?

With the hint given by JakeWharton, I've successfully obtained the wanted result.
I share it here, for anyone looking for a solution.

Is there a better way to find the annotation in the create method of the factory? Or even a better way to achieve my goal in this method?

Here the (simplified) code, without the adapter class, which is the easy part.

#### The example Java class for Json

```
public class Data
{
    @DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    LocalDate date1;
    @DateFormat("ddMMyyyy")
    LocalDate date2;
}
```

#### The DateFormat annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
@interface DateFormat
{
    String value();
}
```

#### The JsonAdapter.Factory based on DateFormat annotation for LocalDate

```
public class DateFormatFactory implements JsonAdapter.Factory
{
    @Override
    public @Nullable JsonAdapter<?> create(Type type_p, Set<? extends Annotation> annotations_p, Moshi moshi_p)
    {
        if (annotations_p.isEmpty() || !type_p.getTypeName().equals(LocalDate.class.getName()))
        {
            return null;
        }
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations_p)
        {
            if (annotation instanceof DateFormat)
            {
                return new LocalDateAdapter(((DateFormat) annotation).value());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: seems alright. you can do `Types.getRawType(type_p) != LocalDate.class`, btw.

Comment: Yes you're right, my way is clumsy... Thank you!